# @synchronized - skip instead of wait

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, mutex

I've got an Objective-c app with several blocks of code where I only want one thread to be able to access it at a time.  Using a @synchronized(self) block works fine for that.

However, I've got one block where I want it to *skip* the block, if another thread is in one of the @synchronized blocks, rather than wait.  Is there a way to simply test if self (or whatever my lock object is) is being held by another synchronized block?

```
// block 1 - wait until lock is available
@synchronized(self) {
    ...
}
...
// block 2 - wait until lock is available
@synchronized(self) {
    ...
}
...
// block 3 - wait until lock is available
@synchronized(self) {
    ...
}
...
// block 4 - skip if lock is not immediately available - no waiting!
howDoISkipIfLockIsNotAvailable(self) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible when using `NSLock` or `NSRecursiveLock` instead of the `@synchronized` syntax sugar. They key feature it offers is the `tryLock` method:

```
NSRecursiveLock *lock = [[NSRecursiveLock alloc] init];

[lock lock];
@try {
    // ... do synchronized stuff
}
@finally {
    [lock unlock];
}

if ([lock tryLock]) {
    @try {
        // do synchronized stuff if possible
    }
    @finally {
        [lock unlock];
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could find something that would work in conjunction with synchronized(), but I guess not... However, in your above example, using an NSRecursiveLock, instead of NSLock, would probably be the better match for the behavior of synchronized(), since synchronized() also works recursively.

Comment: @synchronized just translates to the low-level APIs `pthread_mutex_(un)lock`, and there is of course also a `pthread_mutex_trylock`. So in theory, you could mix up the high-level syntax sugar and the low-level API to achieve the try-case. But in practice, you can't obtain a reference to the same mutex object that @synchronized uses, at least I don't know how...